# Angular 2 : check if routeName is the current one

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, router

I'm working on a project using Angular 2 and I'm facing an issue.
I've created a link component and I can use it like this :

`<cmp-link [routeName]="['Channel/Add']">Add channel</cmp-link>`

This component checks if the current route is the same as the one passed via parameter and if it is, a class is applied. How do I check if the current url is the same as the one provided by the `routeName` ? Well it's ugly.

```
this.isCurrentRoute = this.normalize(currentUrl) === this.routeName[0].toLowerCase();
```

You don't like it ? Me neither. I would like to check if a route is currently activated using it's name.

(In this case, `Channel/Add` is a route name).

I don't figure out how to do this **using a route's name**. I've looked at `Router` and `Instruction`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution for the old router implementation**

I think this sould do the job:

```
router.isRouteActive(router.generate(['Home']))
```

This is not a very nice solution, but the only one I know.

---

The `router.isRouteActive` wants an `Instruction` and is not able to manage the string itself, so you need to generate this `Instruction` with `router.generate()`.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

---

**Note**

As @Clément Flodrops mentioned, this only works with a flat routing-structure. As far as I can see, it's currently not possible to archive this nicely.

Perhaps it would be possible to work with the private `_childeRouter` of the `Router`, but to access this property, we would need to override the `Router`-class.

So I suggest to wait some time, perhaps the Router will support this operation once.

---

**EDIT: new router 3.0.0-alpha**

With the [new router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) you can add a `routerLinkActive="class"` and this will add the class, if the routerLink is active.

Also works, if the routerLink is not directly on the tag with the routerLinkActive:

```
<li role="menuitem" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a href="" [routerLink]="['/home']" title="home" class="control-icon">
        <span class="fa fa-home"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This sould works but in my case, I have nested routes and if I would like to know if a sub route is active over another, I can't : `router.isRouteActive()` always returns `true` because the "root route" is the same.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. I will take a closer look at this problem. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @ClémentFlodrops As far as I see, this unfortunately not possible right now. Except the mentioned way in the edited answer.